# Pandas DataFrame Attribute Error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading in some information from a csv file using a pandas read csv method but the associated DataFrame does not seem to function as expected.

This is the following error:

```
solutiontime = full_data.at[location_name,"solution"]
*** AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'T'
```

with the dataframe being `full_data`. I am hypothesizing that this has something to do with the csv file but I don't know what might be wrong.

`location_name` is simply a string referencing an index within the dataframe and `"solution"` is a column within the dataframe. The `.at` method should return the element with this index and column.

Here is the information from one representative row:

connection  firmware_dsp    firmware_micro  firmware_platform       firmware_rtc_mh firmware_smi_mh firmware_solution_manager   grid_service_active next_billing_cycle_device   next_billing_cycle_rollup
ADAPT_AUTOMATION_20150805152446_c   dongle  None    None    PC-20150331-3.0.4   0.1.7.9 1.3.4897    0.1.6.50.26 FALSE   7/1/16  7/1/16

Comment: What is `location_name`. Further, you will probably have to provide a reproducible example in order to get help